# AWS - Bitnami Apache2 - Not displaying app

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have created a AWS lightsail instance with the Bitnami "NodeJS" image. Normally I setup my servers from scratch but decided to give this pre-configured path a go.

Unfortunately, with this Bitnami setup I can't make sense of Apache2. Normally I would throw my website into /var/www/html and be done with it. That directory doesn't exist..

Currently apache is pointed at `/home/bitnami/htdocs/` (bitnami splashscreen)

Despite me changing the following settings in httpd.conf to point to my webapp

```
DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/app/"
<Directory "/home/bitnami/app/">
```

I get nothing..I even deleted htdocs and somehow still get the bitnami splashscreen?

What am I missing?

Update: I found another conf file at the end of httpd.conf pointing to:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf
```

I updated this to point to my directory - Which worked, although I'm not confident this is right..

Comment: Normally the path would be `/opt/bitnami` from my experience

Comment: Yes there are two locations, one in /home/ and again symlinked to /opt/

Comment: If you run `apachectl -S` or the equivelant via the bitnami script you should be able to find the `DocumentRoot`